# How to set position of specific page using $pdf variable?

Tags: php, dompdf

I have tried those but still failed to use `$pdf->page_script('');`. First of all before to access `$pdf` variable I have set `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);` in dompdf_config.inc.php and `define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);` in dompdf_config.costum.inc.php files and then restarted Apache service. And then I found an answer relative to this question about to use `$pdf->script('');` inline the code to playing with the `$PAGE_NUM` and `$PAGE_COUNT` as `if(){}else{}` parameters. Since I have a task about to print page number which is the potision of last page is differ with the other pages, so that I need to run specific $x $y coordinate only for last page using `if(){}else{}` condition.
This what I did so far:

```
<?php
    
     ob_start();

     session_start();
     require_once("../../../php/dompdf-0.6.2/dompdf_config.inc.php");
     require_once("../../../php/koneksi.php");     

     $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // DOMPDF INSTANCE

     $html .= "<html>";
     $html .= "<head>";
     $html .= "<style>
                @page{
                    margin-top:1.19cm;
                    margin-bottom:1.75cm;
                    margin-left:2cm;
                    margin-right:2cm;
                }
               </style>";
     $html .= "</head>";
     $html .= "<body>";

     $html .= "<script type='text/php'>
        if (isset($pdf) ) {
              $pdf->page_script('
                        $text = $PAGE_NUM . '/' . $PAGE_COUNT;
                        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font('Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif', 'normal');
                        $size = 12;
                        $color = array(0,0,0);
                        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
                        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
                        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
                    if ( $PAGE_NUM > 1 && $PAGE_NUM == $PAGE_COUNT) {
                        $x = 299;
                        $y = 18;
                        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
                    }else{
                        $x = 299;
                        $y = 860;
                        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
                    }
              ');
        }
    </script>";

    ...
    ...
    ...

    $html .= "</body>";
    $html .= "</html>";

    ob_get_clean();
    // $dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true); // Added on 26/03/2020
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("folio", "portrait");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("SK Pelaksana.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

    exit(0);
```

By the way I am using PHP v5.1 and domPDF v.0.6.2.

Comment: @Dharman Not all of us are free to choose the php version running on their server.

Comment: @CalamityJane I think the question is what kind of server you are using that still has PHP 5 installed. I hope it is not for a live site. It would be really irresponsible.

Comment: @Dharman I joined a company in 2019, which has intranet server productive with php 5.2  A nightmare.....  The plan is to redevelop the applications for the aws cloud with docker and of course php 7.4 or 8. However since this will need at least another 18-24 months we are still stuck with php 5.2 for those applications. The knowledge, that php5.2 isn't supported anymore helps zero in this situation.